# ansible: how to split string with multiple delimiters

Tags: regex, split, ansible, ansible-2.x

Here is my output.

```
"result.containers": [
    {
        "Image": "cna.docker.dev/webproxy:1.0.0",
    },
    {
        "Image": "cna-docker-dev-local.docker.dev/lega-customer:1.0.1",
    }
]
```

Here is my code

```
  - name: adding it to groups using images
    add_host:
      name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      groups: '{{ (item.Image.split("/")[1:] | regex_replace("^/", "")).split(":")[0] }}'
    with_items: "{{ result.containers }}"
```

I'm getting the below output:

```
    "add_host": {
    "groups": [
        "['webproxy"
    ],
    "host_name": "vm4.nodekite.com",
    "host_vars": {
    }
```

I would like to filter webproxy from cna.docker.dev/webproxy:1.0.0.
But I'm getting "['webproxy" instead of "webproxy.
Could someone please help!! I even tried this code which fails
(item.Image.split("/")[1:]).split(":")[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.Image | regex_replace('.*?/(.*?):.*', '\\1') }}"
  loop: "{{ result.containers | flatten(1) }}"
```

Example regex is non greedy, adjust as needed.

Gives

```
ok: [localhost] => (item={'Image': 'cna.docker.dev/webproxy:1.0.0'}) => {
    "msg": "webproxy"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'Image': 'cna-docker-dev-local.docker.dev/lega-customer:1.0.1'}) => {
    "msg": "lega-customer"
}
```